# Vkontakte API search general

Tags: vk

I just have a general question regarding the VK search API? Does anyone know what the maximum results that are available for posts returned by search query. I understand it to be very similar to facebook but where facebook limits the number of results does VK do the same thing. Appreciate responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Param "count" - number of posts to return, positive number, default 30, maximum value 200 (100  in some docs).
To get next data portion use param "offset".

http://vk.com/dev/newsfeed.search